# How to perform string manipulation using replace, substring, split, etc

Tags: java, string, replace, split

I have a string data like this

```
string1 = ["car","house","boat"]["one","two","three","four"]["tiger","cat"]
```

I want the output to be like this :

```
first : car,house,boat
second : one,two,three,four
third : tiger,cat
```

How should I perform manipulation on that string?

This is my current attempt:

```
result6 = string1.substring(1);
String[] parts = result6.split("\\[");
String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];
String part3 = parts[2];
result3 = part1.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9,]", "");
result4 = part2.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9,]", "");
result5 = part3.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9,]", "");
result1 = "first : " + part1 + "\n" + "second : " + part2 + "\n" + "third : \n" + part3;
```

But that gets me erroneous output.

Comment: Any time you “error” you should include the error message in the question.

Comment: In result object why did you reolace every thing with blank string?  Why it is require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added `part1`, `part2`, `part3` instead of `result3`, 4, 5 in the `result1` assignment part. And also i suggest you to split according to `][`, i you do the split according to `[` only, you would get an empty string in `parts[0]`.

```
String string1 = "[\"car\",\"house\",\"boat\"][\"one\",\"two\",\"three\",\"four\"][\"tiger\",\"cat\"]";
String parts[] = string1.split("\\]\\[");
String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];
String part3 = parts[2];
String result3 = part1.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9,]", "");
String result4 = part2.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9,]", "");
String result5 = part3.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9,]", "");
String result1 = "first : " + result3 + "\n" + "second : " + result4 + "\n" + "third : " + result5;
System.out.println(result1);
```

**Output:**

```
first : car,house,boat
second : one,two,three,four
third : tiger,cat
```